# what node it is

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I[image] get some procedural textures from blender kit and the node is red what is this? I tried to replace it with a mapping node but the socket isn't the same.
thank you

Comment: You're using Blender 2.80 so that node might not be available in that version. The node setup may have been created with Blender 2.93.

Comment: I second that. And think that John Eason should add this as the answer here. To find out what node it is it would be nice to have a look at the blend file.

Answer (score 5):

You're using Blender 2.80 so that node might not be available in that version. The node setup may have been created with Blender 2.93. We'd need to see the blend file to confirm that.

Comment: thank you john this link to the material from blender kit

asset_base_id:c5457873-b652-4cdd-9f0c-b3aab96bc4a1 asset_type:material

i cannot use blender 2.93 with my old laptop
is there a way to manipulate to get the same result without using blender 2.93

in normal I can change to mapping node and its okay but in this, i confused with the other socket (in image ) where to get location socket

Comment: I'm afraid that link means and does nothing as far as we are concerned. You'll have to upload your blend file to [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/) and put a link to it in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Considering its inputs: `Vector`, `Location`, `Rotation`, and `Scale`, and it's output `Vector`, I'm pretty sure it's the **Mapping** node:

[image]

I don't know why it's red, perhaps John Eason is right that you loaded a file saved in a newer version of Blender than the one you're using. It's not necessarily a node that your version is missing, a different implementation of this node in newer versions is (probably) enough to bug out older versions like that.

Comment: The mapping node in version 2.79 to 2.83 looks from the Blender docs as if it just has a single Vector input, whereas that in the 2.93 version has four possible inputs as the original image above shows. I'm not really familiar with nodes, but I guess 2.80 is getting confused when it finds all the extra inputs.